# Printing Excel using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop, printing

Does anybody have any idea how to print an excel file programatically using C# and the Excel Interop?  If so, can you please provide code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In order to print, you can make use of the  [Worksheet.PrintOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.printout.aspx) method. You can omit any or all of the optional arguments by passing in [Type.Missing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.missing.aspx). If you omit all of them, it will default to printing out one copy from your active printer. But you can make use of the arguments to set the number of copies to print, collation, etc. See help on the  [Worksheet.PrintOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.printout.aspx) method for more.

The example they show in the help file is:

```
private void PrintToFile()
{
    // Make sure the worksheet has some data before printing.
    this.Range["A1", missing].Value2 = "123";
    this.PrintOut(1, 2, 1, false, missing, true, false, missing);
}
```

But unless you need to change the default settings, you can simply pass in [Type.Missing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.missing.aspx) for all the arguments. Here's an example using automation to open an Excel Workbook, print the first page, and then shut down:

```
void PrintMyExcelFile()
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    // Open the Workbook:
    Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
        @"C:\My Documents\Book1.xls",
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);

    // Get the first worksheet.
    // (Excel uses base 1 indexing, not base 0.)
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    // Print out 1 copy to the default printer:
    ws.PrintOut(
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    // Cleanup:
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ws);

    wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);

    excelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Mike

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to show a print dialogue instead of straight away printing the document...would ya?

Comment: Yes, but I think you should ask another question for this. The answer needs a little bit of explanation and the command itself will look bad in a comment (there's 30 optional parameters for which you'll have to use 30 Type.Missings). Its an easy answer, but it's a bit much to stuff into a comment I think... So start a new Q, i'll be lookning for it. ;-)

Comment: Namespace:  System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: Hi John, right, the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' namespace is used for the 'Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject' calls to clean up memory at the end. It isn't needed for any of the 'PrintOut' method, nor any of the other calls to the Excel object model. Good pickup, thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do, but I need to print individual sheets in Excel to a PDF printer. Every time I do however, the PDF gets corrupted in some way or another. I've tried numerous PDF printers (Adobe, PDF955, PDFCreator, AMYUNI) and they all seem to do the same thing. I've used your example but set the printername, filename and printofile flag to true with no success. Any ideas how I'd get that to work?

Comment: @MikeRosenblum This code works very well.  Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Important improvement is the code for select the Printer, for example:

```
var printers = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;

int printerIndex = 0;

foreach(String s in printers)
{
    if (s.Equals("Name of Printer"))
    {
        break;
    }
    printerIndex++;
}

xlWorkBook.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,printers[printerIndex], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers already given are good but I just thought I keep it much simpler with more options for showing a dialogue box and defining the orientation of the page for printing.

```
private void PrintExcel()
{
    string filePath = "C:\file\location\here\";
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    // Open Workbook:
    Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

    // Define the orientation for the page
    ((Excel._Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet).PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;

    //Decide which worksheet to print
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    // Option to print with or to show dialogue box
    bool userDidntCancel = excelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrint].Show();

    // Option to print out wihtout the dialogue box. 
    // WARNING: Do not use Dialogue option and this at the same time. 
    // It will print the page even if you cancel the dialogue print option.
    ws.PrintOut();

    // Cleanup your code
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ws);

    wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);

    // Close/Exit File
    excelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);

}
```

I hope this bit helps someone. :D