# Why am I getting Show method of Dialog class failed in c# when using the xlDialogPrint.show method?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to print a Microsoft Excel document in C# using visual studio and I get a Show method of Dialog class failed exception every time I attempt to execute this piece of code:

```
bool userDidntCancel =
       ExcelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrint].Show(
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Here is the full code I'm using:

```
            Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(
            PATH,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    try
    {
        bool userDidntCancel =
           ExcelApp.Dialogs[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogPrint].Show(
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
    catch
    {
        ExcelApp.Quit();
        File.Delete("Container Status.xls");
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854693/printing-excel-using-interop did you search for even 1 second?

Comment: Yes, in fact I did and didn't not find an answer.  The code you've posted a link to isn't even the same thing!  I'm using a xldialogprint box not just a printout method but thanks for your a hole comment.