# Print Excel Worksheet/Workbook

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, excel-interop, closedxml

I'm trying to improve performance of a C# Winform project.

Previously, generate an Excel file was during 100000ms (using Office.Interop.Excel).
Using [ClosedXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) it is about 5000ms. Really Great. But now I need to print this Excel document (only a Worksheet or the entire workbook)

I was doing this before (using office interop) :

```
public void PrintCurrentWorksheet()
{
    this._activeWorksheet.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
public void PrintWorkbook()
{
    this._activeWorbook.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

But now type of `_activeWorkbook` and `_activeWorksheet` are `XLWorkbook` and `IXLWorksheet`. So there is no `Printout` method. I could not find a print method and I suppose there is not because OpenXml is not relied to Excel. Am I right?

I could not find a Shell command to print a Worksheet.

So, is there a simple way to print a Workbook/Worksheet without using Interop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries that allow you to read and write Excel-compatible files are, like most libraries, "[headless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_software)".

The code in them can be used to write data in a format that Excel (and compatible applications) understand, but they generally do not offer a (link to a) user interface, nor a way to render the contents of the Excel file to another file format or a printer. Because that is outside the scope of the library. Reading and writing files is one thing, rendering their contents properly is a whole other thing.

There are libraries that do support printing Excel files, such as [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Printing+Workbooks).

You can always only [use interop to print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854693/printing-excel-using-interop), while generating the document using libraries. Or you can [send the "print" verb to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print), which will print using default settings to the default printer.

Comment: "default settings to the default printer" You mean Default settings of the Excel File? So I could use "print verb" and ClosedXml `PrintArea` to print a single Worksheet?

Comment: I don't know, try it. :)