# Change default printer setting before print Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, printing, interop

I want to change the default settings of printer before printing by `Print Document` I am getting my default printer name and can set default `Paper Source` for this Printer, but I can't print Excel file with this because this is using `Stream Reader`.

I tried to use `Microsoft Interop` but I can't find where I can fix `Default Paper Source` for my Printer.

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks for your advices. Regards!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854693/printing-excel-using-interop

Comment: Thanks. But I try use `Worksheet.PrintOut() ` but I can't find how can choose the tray of printer before printing something use Interop.